# Calling a property of object when I don't know it's class in Obj-c

Tags: objective-c, metaprogramming

I have an array of objects, each of different, under my control, class.

Each class has a property `id`

So calling object.id with some kind of casting works.

How can I do this kind of code, without casting

```
for(id obj in objects){
  NSLog(@"%ld", obj.id);
}
```

Comment: I'd add a protocol that has your `id` property on it, have all your classes conform to the protocol, and use the protocol instead.

Comment: The best approach would be to make all of your classes implement a protocol that defines `id`.

Comment: then I would do `for (id<myProtocol> obj in objects)`?

Comment: FYI - avoid naming your property `id`. `id` has a special meaning in Objective-C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
for (id obj in objects) {
    if ([obj respondsToSelector:@selector(id)])
        [obj performSelector:@selector(id)];
}
```

Note that if you don't check if the object responds to the selector, you're risking crashing your app with an unrecognized selector exception.

Comment: This won't work as-is. Based on the OP's code, the `id` property returns a `long`. Therefore you can't use `performSelector` to get the return value since the return value isn't an object. Just replace `performSelector` with `long val = [obj id];`.

Answer (score 0):

You could be able to use the KVC method `valueForKey:@"id"`

Otherwise if you're looking for selectors I think you can check them for reponse with a `respondsToSelector:@selector(id)`

Though I wanna suggest two things :

1. Don't put objects of different kinds in the same array, that's just meant to confuse you.
2. Cast them if you can, it's definitly clearer and more comfortable because it gets you to use your properties. Just make sure you're casting the proper objects !

Comment: why is casting safer?

Comment: Well when you code you will know that you're casting a "Car" item and you know that "Car" only has ".seats" and ".pilot" for example. This won't confuse you into trying to use .jump on your car.

Though it's not safer in the way that it can't give you trouble if you're trying to cast the wrong object into a car.

Comment: But I feel like "safer" wasn't the right word to use

Comment: Using casting is not safer, if the method doesn't exist, you will still get an unrecognized selector exception. Using different type of objects in your array is perfectly fine. However, make them conform to the same protocol is preferred. This ensures, as Zil said, that you're calling a method that you know exists on these objects. i.e. `for (id<MyProtocol> obj in objects) { // code here }`

Comment: Alrighty. But I don't know i've always tried to have "same-kind" arrays, even if I have to split it into several arrays that I keep in another array. Maybe i've been taught the religion differently ! ;)

Comment: Potato, potâto. (wow, terrible at typing audible accents) In the end, it's all casting anyway. ;)